# Are there Andoid versions > 2.3 for my Sony Xperia ST25i (as of July 2012)?

Tags: android-versions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my device get the Android 4.0 update (Ice Cream Sandwich)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14766/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-0-update-ice-cream-sandwich)

Like the question says, are there higher versions of Android for my phone? Will Sony release a 4.0 update for my phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not officially yet. According to [Sony](http://blogs.sonymobile.com/products/2012/05/25/update-on-ice-cream-sandwich-rollout-for-xperia-smartphones/), the Xperia U will be getting ICS in Q3 of this year.

That said I believe there are now some beta 3rd party ROMs floating around with various degrees of success.