# Samsung Tab P7500. How to upgrade to Ice Cream Sandwich?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my device get the Android 4.0 update (Ice Cream Sandwich)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14766/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-0-update-ice-cream-sandwich)

is the update for Ice Cream Sandwich for the Samsung Tab 10.1 WiFi + 3G available yet? From where should I learn about it?

Answer (score 1):

No official update to ICS is currently available for your device. However, Samsung says that they will be providing *either* an ICS update (Ice Cream Sandwich), *or* a feature upgrade that provides similar capabilities as ICS.

[Source](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/newsalert/view?spp_news_seq=36900)

> NOTE: The following Ice Cream Sandwich (ICS) tutorial can support you upgrading your Galaxy >S II to Android 4.0 ICS. It will be available for other Galaxy devices shortly.
>   For select models where ICS will not be available a feature update alternative will be >offered giving similar functionality to ICS.