# Will there be 4.0 (ICS) Android version for i9000 phones?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my device get the Android 4.0 update (Ice Cream Sandwich)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14766/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-0-update-ice-cream-sandwich)

Will there be 4.0 Android version for i9000 phones? I can't find any answers online.