# How can I get Android 4.0.4 on my XPERIA Neo V?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I asked some questions about rooting before but I didn't realize it all was supposed to be done on an MT11a with **Android 4.0.4**. I have **2.3.4**, so I just rolled everything back. Where and how can I install this version? I am seeing videos (YouTube, for example) where people have this OS installed in this very same device.

Comment: Did you have tried Sony Update Service? download this software and follow instructions to update your phone easily to an original stock ICS ROM.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When will my device get the Android 4.0 update (Ice Cream Sandwich)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14766/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-0-update-ice-cream-sandwich)

Comment: Not really a dupe, @Chahk (Peter and some of us had that yesterday on chat), as ICS is already released. So the question is not *when* -- but rather **how**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to visit the [Update page for Neo V](http://www.sonymobile.com/gb/software/phones/xperia-neo-v/) for closer information on how to update. It not only tells you what has changed, but also provides you with the required downloads.

The link is to the UK version. I could not find any link for Argentina, and the Brazil page does not even list the Neo V. So you might want to check around for yourself -- at least that's somewhere to start with.