# Does Galaxy Mini S5570 support ICS?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 2.3-gingerbread, updates, rom-flashing, samsung-galaxy-mini

I have a [Samsung Galaxy Mini S5570](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_mini_s5570-3725.php) running Android 2.3.6 (Gingerbread). I know that the official support for Galaxy Mini ends here. But I have come across tutorials for upgrading from Gingerbread to ICS. What I want to know is, is it safe to upgrade my phone? Or will I encounter problems later on after upgrading?

Comment: See [When will my device get the Android 4.0 update (Ice Cream Sandwich)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14766/16575) for official update statements. As there are so many Galaxy Minis around, I'm not sure which one you refer to; but you might check at [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/16575) to see if there's any ROM with ICS to be found already.

Comment: Its an S5570. There is no official support for ICS on S5570. Is there a problem if i install it througfh cyanogenmod?

Comment: If there is a compatible build available, I'd say no. Except, may be, performance might be an issue. Device specs look a little low (600 MHz, 384 MB RAM, that's not that much). I'd check the feedback of those using this combination.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, there is no official ICS for Galaxy Mini.

But CyanogenMod 10 and 10.1 work on the Galaxy Mini. I'm using cyanogenmod 10.1 RC5. It's a Jelly Bean ROM, but it works perfectly with my Mini. You can [find it on xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2085347).

Answer (score 0):

The offical ics does not work on galaxy mini. but we can run it by cyanogenmod. I have tried it everything works fine . it has both pros and cons
pros
1. you can feel the Ics os very good.
2. nice graphics 
 cons
1. battry life will be redused 
 2. memory will not be suffician to run apps that support in ICS 
 speed of phone will be redused considerably

Answer (score -1):

the Ics will not support to the galaxy mini or galaxy pop

Comment: Can you backup up that statement?