# How do I troubleshoot the updgrade process of  my ASUS Transformer to 3.2.1?

Tags: updates, 3.1-honeycomb, asus-eee-pad-transformer, 3.2-honeycomb

I just got a new ASUS Eee Transformer TF101.  (Ironically on the day the Prime is officially released/announced.  Oh well).

It came with Android 3.1 per the Settings page.  I tried Settings: About tablet: System Update and am told there are no updates available.

I read that 3.2 is available on these devices.  (I know 4.0/ICS is still a future thing).

How do I get to 3.2 on this device?  No obvious downloads on Asustek web page.

I am on my WiFi at home, checking mail, downloading apps, etc.

So how do I troubleshoot why the Over The Air upgrade did not show an available update, when there has been one available since early 2011 (many moons ago).

I am logged in to my Google Account. (I have my Gmail, Google Voice, and Youtube accounts all connecting ok).

What else can I check or look at, to understand why the OTA upgrade is not being made available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When will my device get the Android 3.x update (Honeycomb)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7680/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-3-x-update-honeycomb)

Comment: @RyanConrad I already know from lots of web links that 3.2.1 is available on my device.  The issue is it is NOT getting the update.   So how do I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

For a manual approach, I found a [download link for the Firmware](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=20&s=16&m=Eee%20Pad%20Transformer%20TF101&os=32) off the Asus site.

I think my mistake earlier was in the download pages OS selector I looked at WinXP, Win7, never considered (or noticed) that Android was an OS option.

Then you download and unzip the 250 meg file.

Then you copy it to an SD card, with ASUS as the folder at the root.

Pop it into the Tranformer, and you get a notification that it is preparing the SD card, and then that there is a Software Update available.

At that point, you are at the same basic functionality as the Over The Air upgrade path.  Make sure you are plugged in (or do not run out of power).

However, this is a workaround, as opposed to fixing the core issue, of why the OTA upgrade was not available.