# Huawei ideos s7 slim Honeycomb update - is it possible somehow?

Tags: updates, 3.1-honeycomb

I got this new tablet and I have to write an application which live streams video. I know that since 3.1 this is natively supported on Android. Since the s7 is a tablet I think that there should be some way to update its 2.2 to 3.1. Is there a way to do this? Little hint where to start looking? Cyanogen doesn't have anything for s7.

Comment: CyanogenMod doesn't have a Honeycomb-based version, anyway. Related: [How do I update the OS in my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/how-do-i-update-the-os-in-my-device) and [When will my device get the Android 3.x update (Honeycomb)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7680/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-3-x-update-honeycomb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[XDA has nothing](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=896) except for some attempts at getting Gingerbread on it.

I would expect you're out of luck since Honeycomb wasn't open-source, and porting was therefore very difficult.  It's possible that someone will mod CM9 (Android 4.0) to run on it, so I would wait and see.