# Is it possible to update from 2.1 to 2.3?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, 2.1-eclair, 2.3-gingerbread

I've got a galaxy s device and want to update it to latest android releace. I'd like to skip the 2.2 update and just do the 2.3 update. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly possible to skip Android versions, but 2.3 has not been released for the Galaxy S.  See [When will my phone get the Android 2.3 update (Gingerbread)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-3-update-gingerbread)

You could try a custom ROM, however; check out [XDA's SGS Development forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=665) to find one.

Comment: I saw that link, but though it was confirmed couldn't find any information on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

There is a beta version of a custom Gingerbread ROM made by Darky (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=814091), but it's still a bit tricky to install and not a stable release. It works almost flawlessly on my phone, but there are some bugs. If you'd like to have an official or a stable ROM, best to wait.