# Android 2.3 for HTC Wild Fire

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, htc-wildfire

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get the Android 2.3 update (Gingerbread)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-3-update-gingerbread)

Is there any update on Update for HTC Wildfire to Android 2.3 . I have android 2.2 .

Answer (score 1):

From the [list of when phones will get 2.3](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-3-update-gingerbread):

**HTC Wildfire (buzz)**

- OTA: never *(source: official mail from HTC support; cause: doesn't meet the min. requirements, eg. 1GHz)*
- Unofficial:

  - 2/15/2011 ([CyanogenMod](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/15843-cyanogenmod-7-for-buzz-v700-rc1-2152011/))