# Upgrade Samsung Galaxy Tab to Android 2.3.3

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-tab, updates, device-firmware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get the Android 2.3 update (Gingerbread)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-3-update-gingerbread)
>   [How do I update Android on my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/13510/1465)

I live in Uruguay and I've recently bought a Samsung Galaxy Tab. The device's system is Android 2.2 and I want to upgrade it to 2.3.3 so I can deploy an app I've been working on, that won't run on previous versions of Android.

I've read on the internet that it's possible to upgrade the device by doing it through Samsung Kies or on the device settings. The problem is that the device says that it's up to date and that there are no updates available. I'm positive that the device's firmware version is 2.2 so I'm starting to think that this upgrade is not available on my region.

Does anyone knows how can I upgrade my device or the reason why I can't upgrade it?

Thanks in advance.

Mikywan.

Answer (score 1):

In May Samsung begin rolling updates to 2.3.3 for European devices, starting with Italy.

At this time (June 2011) there is no word of an update to 2.3.3 being available in South America or Netherlands, so you will have to wait some time, or you can go to XDA-Developers forums and follow the [instructions to manually update your Galaxy Tab](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1083971)