# Gingerbread on Samsung Galaxy Mini

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get the Android 2.3 update (Gingerbread)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-3-update-gingerbread)

I recently bought Samsung Galaxy Mini with Froyo installed on it. Can any one tell me when can I get Gingerbread on it using Kies? I did not buy it from any operator. Also, I live in Pakistan (in case region matters for updates).

I do not have any experience of using Android before (though I have written a couple of apps for it :P ).

Answer (score 0):

You could send a mail to Samsung Pakistan, and ask them.

The ROM for the Galaxy Mini (and every Samsung) has specific Samsung components (TouchWiz, Samsung Apps, etc). And comes with a language pack specific for each region. Eventually every provider can add his stuff.

So it is up to the combination Samsung and provider when (or if) a new version of Android is released.

I know of some friends that have been able to upgrade their provider branded phone to Gingerbread, while my non-branded phone does not have the update (yet).