# How to upgrade to Android 2.3 from 2.2?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, updates, t-mobile-sidekick-4g

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I update the OS in my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/how-do-i-update-the-os-in-my-device)

I own a Sidekick 4g currently running Android 2.2 (Froyo) and I want to upgrade to 2.3 (Gingerbread) to use my front camera on video chat with family on Skype. How do I upgrade my Sidekick?

Comment: Have you heard of an official, or unofficial, update to 2.3? The sidekick uses another "custom" version of android by samsung, and they haven't even rolled out TouchWiz Gingerbread to their Galaxy S devices yet, officially.

Answer (score 3):

If there is an official update to Android 2.3 (check the post on [Gingerbread updates](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-3-update-gingerbread)) then you'll get a notice on your phone (eventually). Just follow the instructions.

If there's not an official update and you don't want to wait for one, you'll need to [root your phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-device) and install a Custom ROM.