# How do I know when updates are available for my phone?

Tags: updates, carriers

I've got an Optimus T, and being new to the world of Android, I'm confused as to how I'm supposed to update my operating system.

The phone is carrier locked to T Mobile. Does this mean that I can only get updates from them? Can I tell the phone to look on another server? How can I tell if I have the latest build of Android that's available for my device?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/how-do-i-update-the-os-in-my-device

Answer (score 3):

To check for phone updates, go into Applications > Settings > About Phone and tap System updates or check for updates. However, if a new update comes out, then you should get a notification informing you so and giving you update instructions. If you root your phone, then you could install unofficial updates that are not from T-Mobile. There are instructions at http://forums.androidcentral.com/t-mobile-optimus-t/43138-how-root-lg-optimus-t.html if you want to do so.

Comment: When I check I'm told that the server is unavailable.

Comment: That's weird... Make sure that you have a network or wifi connection.

Comment: Oh, I do. I'm on WiFi.

Comment: That's really weird...

Answer (score 1):

To copy from Al's answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12218/how-to-upgrade-to-android-2-3-from-2-2):

> If there is an official update to Android 2.3 (check the post on [Gingerbread updates](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-3-update-gingerbread)) then you'll get a notice on your phone (eventually). Just follow the instructions.
>
> If there's not an official update and you don't want to wait for one, you'll need to [root your phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-device) and install a Custom ROM.