# How do I get Android 2.3 on my Verizon Droid 2?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, rooting, 2.3-gingerbread, verizon, motorola-droid-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get the Android 2.3 update (Gingerbread)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-3-update-gingerbread)
>   [How do I root my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-device)

I have a Droid 2 with Verizon and the Android version is 2.2 (froyo).

I am looking to update to 2.3 (gingerbread) but when I go to the check for updates section it says it's up to date. How can I get 2.3? I have never rooted before but if that's what I have to do to get it then I will. Any resources that could point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: This post is a good place to keep an eye ono to see if anyone's heard of an official version coming http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-3-update-gingerbread

Answer (score 0):

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1124744

It's not finalized, so make sure you read everything.

Comment: Answers that are little more than a link to an external site are no answer at all.