# How can I install an updated version of Android on my device?

Tags: updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get the Android 2.3 update (Gingerbread)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-3-update-gingerbread)

I have an Android mobile device which has Android 2.2 and I want to update it to Android 2.3.

What possible ways are there for me to update the OS?

Comment: You don't say what phone you have, this makes a big difference to the answer. See this previous question for a list of release dates for official Android 2.3 updates for various phone models: [When will my phone get the Android 2.3 update (Gingerbread)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-3-update-gingerbread)

Comment: Actually, I m developing an application for checking the compatibility of OS version. For this upgrading OS in device mode help me to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. If your device manufacturer has released an update, you can use that to update your android. Manufacturer updates are generally released OTA, and they are device specific so you need to check whether the manufacturer has released an update for your device or not.
2. Install a custom ROM. Custom ROMs like [cyanogenmod](/questions/tagged/cyanogenmod) can be used to upgrade Android but remember that it is not official upgrade and you lose the device warranty provided by your device manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks @ Atul Goyal. I have one more thing to clarify. It is possible to get the Android OS separately [official version]..? or how about getting Custom ROM for the same.?

Comment: @GnanamR just the bare Android OS won't work on most devices (except possibly for Nexus models) as it won't include drivers, etc for your model's hardware. If you just want to test with the bare OS you may be best using the Android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

@Atul Goyal's answer is not very accurate.  You can usually get both stock ROMs and updates from the manufacturers website.  Generally they are .ZIP files that you put on the root of your phone and flash.  If you can't get them from the manufacturer, usually you can find them on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/).