# Update Android on non famous manufacture Android Phone

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, updates, rom

I have a [QMobile A100](http://www.qmobile.com.pk/71/A100.html) with Android 2.2.1 (which is very old). I want to upgrade it to the new version (2.3 Gingerbread). In `Settings > About phone` it shows that there are no updates to the firmware.

How should I update my device? It is not a popular phone and I cannot find an updated ROM for it.

If it matters, the phone has a 500 MHz CPU, 200 MB RAM with 250 MB ROM.

Comment: please state if you are ready to root your phone or not (because you'll need to root before anything.

Comment: I couldn't find any thing about your phone could you tell me more specs (resolution,GPS, WIFI ,etc.)

Comment: @MohamedEssam I've edited the question and added the link to the device product page.

Comment: @Zuul there isn't any custom ROM made for this phone so I searched for the nearest specs phone it was only one called `Gigabyte GSmart G1317 Rola` which also had no custom ROMs ,unfortunately nobody can answer this Q unless he makes a ROM specifically for this phone or the other one(the one that's very near it,so the conclusion is there is no answer to this Q.

Comment: Related: [When will my phone get the Android 2.3 update (Gingerbread)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-3-update-gingerbread) and [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)